# How does this dynamo work?

Tags: generator, magnetic-flux, dynamo

I disassembled a dynamo-fuelled torch and I found this set-up. 
Now, what I know is that the led should be lighted up by the electromagnetic force generated by the time-varying flux within the coil. Thus I wonder how can the rotation of the magnet (which is the thing I hold in my hand in the second and the third picture) generate a time-varying flux within the coil?

I don't understand how could the magnetic fields' lines be, however, as far as I can see, the rotation of the magnet shouldn't change the flux within the coil!

I think it has to do with the "metallic teeth" arranged over and under the coil  (there are four over and four under it)... But I don't know how.

PS: From the picture I took it can't be seen but the coil is NOT inside the magnet. In fact, the magnet just leans on the "teeth structure" and all of the teeth are inside a cavity in the magnet (which can be seen in the photos).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coil does not need to be inside the physical magnet, but it does (and is) inside the magnetic field produced by the magnet.

The magnet has multiple N and S poles around its perimeter, and the 'metallic teeth' are pole pieces that transfer the magnetic field to be around the coil.
Rotating the magnet rotates the field.

Comment: It might be a dumb question, but how can a single magnet have more than two poles? I don't think I've never seen one

Comment: @Elia Try looking at [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Magnetic_quadrupole_moment.svg/1200px-Magnetic_quadrupole_moment.svg.png); that should give you an idea!

Comment: use another magnet as a probe to discover where the poles are

Comment: @Felthry If you use 4 dipoles I don't have any objections, however, if you have one single magnet, which is one single "object", is a different thing, and I still don't understand how can exist a magnet with more than 2 poles

Comment: @jsotola Wow, I already tried it before but I tested the outside and I found nothing at that time. This time I extracted the magnet, which is a toroid, and indeed, I found 4 poles... So they really exist :D ...But I still don't understand them

Comment: Everything is a dipole at an atomic level. Imagine sticking those four dipoles together into a single object.

Comment: multiple magnets glued together ..... btw: this is not a place to ask about multi-pole magnets .... they do not really have anything to do with electronics .... would you ask a technical question about tire rubber composition in an automobile repair shop, just because they install tires on vehicles?

Comment: Have a look at the following for conceptual ideas.  -  http://overunity.com/17389/a-bunch-of-questions-regarding-radially-magetized-ring-magnet/dlattach/attach/164893/image//  -  http://www.hsmagnets.com/permanent-magnets/multipole-radial-ring-magnets/